# Console alternatives

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

So my school blocked developer tools, I am kind of able to edit the html with Xray Goggles, but I cannot do anything in the console while I am developing. I don't want to use bookmarklets, since they can't view the console, only execute script. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. But you can use code to make errors logged somewhere!